# How to ensure two XLS files are the same

Tags: excel, vba, hash, controls, version

I have a spreadsheet that connects to Database and wanted to, somehow, ensure that the spreadsheet used in tests is the same version as the one in production.
The most important to check is the vba code itself.
We thought first to create a Hash from the workbook. The only point is that we need to change the string to connect to the test or production database, so this is an 'expected' difference between then.

Any ideas?

Ps.: And yes, we do plan to migrate this to java or something.. but until there we need to deal with it :)

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could still do an assertion the the files are identical, via a hash or some other method, but you would have have 3 versions, development, test, and production.

The other thing you could do, which might be easier to maintain, is to have one spreadsheet that is identical, but read your database string from a separate config file.

Then you could deploy 1 version of the spreadsheet, but 3 different config files. This would also be useful if you have multiple workbooks that use the same connection string.

Comment: I liked your idea of the config files.. First I'll have to encrypt the password somehow. Let me try that and will return to you.. but definitely a good idea

Comment: Argh, not really.. We have a problem that sometimes the spreadsheet stores some information of production in the sheets itself so we wouldn't be able to deploy only one spreadsheet as tests information could go to production. Another problem is that when excel saves the workbook, it changes some binary data in some VBA files so my idea to read it from java won't work as well. And my last hope was to export the files from inside excel, but then it's not an automatic process as we need to log in into worksheet.. Sad story :(